# Uncheck an html checkbox with for label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using the following html to display a checkbox with an image:

```
<div class="testClass">
<input id="111" name="compare_checkbox" type="checkbox" />                      
<label for="111">
    <i class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Compare</b>
</label>
</div>
```

I need to uncheck the checkbox in certain conditions. I am using the following jquery : $('#111')[0].checked = false;

This works fine if I don't have the label. When I have the label, I don't get any errors in console (either Chrome or Firefox), but the checkbox does not uncheck.

Comment: Code or did not happened.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/umAsw/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Just letting you know that you cannot have numbers leading your element ID. Please see [Element ID in HTML Document ~ Naming Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024855/element-id-in-html-document-naming-question#2024867). Hope this is helpful to you :)

Solution:

```
<div class="testClass">
<input id="one" name="compare_checkbox" type="checkbox" />                      
<label for="one">
    <i class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Compare</b>
</label>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tLsK7/

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox states are best handled cross-browser with jQuery's `prop` function, regardless of whether or not the checkbox has an associated `<label>`.

```
$('#element').prop("checked", true); // Checks a checkbox.
$('#element').prop("checked", false); // Unchecks a checkbox.
```

Comment: There must be something else in your JavaScript preventing it from working, because it works with the label present [**in this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjHXT/1/)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that, according to everything below HTML5, `'111'` **is not a valid ID** for an element. Unless you're using HTML5, the ID must start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

working fine with for='111'

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/spaipalle/umAsw/3/

```
$('#111').click(function(){
if($('#111').is(":checked")){
        alert('checked');
        $('#111')[0].checked = false; // uncheck it
}else{
        alert('unchecked');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the id of the element?  I don't think ID's can be made up of just numbers, or at least they can't start with a number